# Excel function to return characters before second occurrence of a specified character

Tags: excel

I want a function to return the first two names in a cell for example

"Jones, Anna Mary" will return "Jones Anna"

I tried =LEFT(A1, FIND(" ",A1)-1) but it returns only Jones.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You could get everything before the 2nd space by using this version

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-1)`

That would still include the comma so if you don't want that you can add a SUBSTITUTE function to remove commas, i.e.

`=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-1),",","")`

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-",2),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-",2),1)-1)
```

I used the SUBSTITUTE() function to replace the second space with a hyphen. I then used the FIND() function on the SUBSTITUTE string.

Comment: It would be sufficient, though, to use just A1 as the first argument of LEFT function, i.e. `=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-",2),1)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add another answer, that works even if some of the cells don't have two or more spaces:

=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ",255),2), 255))

(from mikerickson at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/703900-delete-everything-after-second-space-each-cell.html)

(and, of course, if you're using a non-English system - like I am here in Sweden - you might have to replace all commas with semicolons.)